# jquery not firing for button event?

Tags: jquery, html, image, button, file-upload

I have a situation where I want to display a graphical button for a user to click to initiate a file upload.

I've created a normal file upload input like this:

`<input style="display:none;" id="file" type="file" name="file">`

Note that it's set to display:none so I can "overlay" the graphical button.

Then I created an input of type="image" for the actual image button people will click on. It appears, as intended, overlaying where the hidden file upload button would be.

`<input id="uploadButton" type="image" src="images/choosefile-button.png" style="width:256px;height:57px;" />`

Now I'm using a jQuery script documented in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8q6MAedPiJY) to handle the click event and pass it to the real, hidden file upload button for execution of the file selection dialog.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var intervalFunc = function () {                                               
        $('#file').html($('#file').val());
        );
        $('#uploadButton').on('click', function() {
        $('#file').click();
        setInterval(intervalFunc, 1);
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click the graphical button, the file upload dialog doesn't appear. All that happens is that the URL changes by adding the x/y coordinate parameters of where the click occurred on the image button. I've checked that jQuery is linked in the file, and it is. Any idea whether what I'm trying to do will even work? Do I have to adapt the script to detect the proper x/y value range for this button and then trigger the click on the underlying, hidden real button?

Comment: The video is a bit long, so here's the point in the video that shows the whole code of the jQuery script. https://youtu.be/8q6MAedPiJY?t=5m35s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appear to return expected results at stacksnippets, when remove syntax error at `);` following `$('#file').html($('#file').val())` Note, not certain about purpose of including `setInterval` ? Also `input` element does not have `.innerHTML`

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#uploadButton").on("click", function() {
        $("#file").click();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="uploadButton" type="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics" style="width:256px;height:57px;" />
<input style="display:none;" id="file" type="file" name="file">
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. It works great now!